# dynamically change the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

We have a web app that was developed in Asp.net 4.0 WebForms
The URL is, for example, www.mysite.com
originally it was a single Database for the Application.

Now we have to make it so multiple customers can use it, against developers advice we are using multiple sql DB

So now I need to figure out how to make all our pages
work with each customer like this
Instead of everyone going here
www.mysite.com/login.aspx

I need to be able to make the URLs work this way
www.mysite.com/Cust1/ redirects to www.mysite.com/Cust1/ Login.aspx

Then all other URLs the customer uses will have Cust1 in them

Comment: Are you creating a instance of the site per customer? So www.mysite.com/Cust1 is one site with its database and www.mysite.com/Cust2 is another with its own database?

Comment: If you're able to re-write this application (which I know is probably not going to happen) MVC does all of this for you. Otherwise I believe you want to look at URL re-writing http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite or http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: NO it is 1 instance of IIS using the C# asp.net code and then it is going to dynamically connect to each customer based on the /Cust1 or /Cust11222

Comment: 1 iis server with 1 instance of the web application using multiple sql DB, GOd i wish i could use MVC